# Prove that $\left\vert\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\sin (k)}\right\vert\leq\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\sin \left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Prove that 
$$\left\vert\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\sin (k)}\right\vert\leq\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\sin \left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash\{1\}.$$

Please show all passages and what theorems used.
Thanks.

This is what i made:
$$\left\vert\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\sin (k)}\right\vert=\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left\vert\sin (k)\right\vert}$$

but

$$\left\vert\sin (k)\right\vert=\frac{\left\vert e^{ik}-e^{-ik}\right\vert}{\left\vert 2i\right\vert}=\frac{\left\vert e^{ik}-e^{-ik}\right\vert}{2}=\frac{\left\vert e^{-ik}\right\vert}{2}\left\vert e^{2ik}-1\right\vert=\frac{1}{2}\left\vert e^{2ik}-1\right\vert\quad\Rightarrow\quad\left\vert\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\sin (k)}\right\vert=\frac{1}{2^{n}}\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left\vert e^{2ik}-1\right\vert}$$

Whit similar steps:

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\sin \left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}=\left(-2\right)^{1-n}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{n}}-1\right)}=2^{1-n}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(1-e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{n}}\right)}$$

and then

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left\vert e^{2ik}-1\right\vert}\leq 2\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(1-e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{n}}\right)}$$

I don't understand how i should continue...

...if we write

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}{\sin \left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}=\frac{2n}{2^n}$$

then

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left\vert e^{2ik}-1\right\vert}\leq 2n$$

is it true $\forall n$?

Comment: @Behaviour and the others, was this closed because it's actually homework and shows no effort?

Comment: In the first line of you computation, it should be $|e^{-ik}|$, not $e^{-ik}$.